# "Glance" is to sight as _ is to hearing?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a word which describes a brief auditory examination. Analogous to “glance” in the sense of the following example:

> At first glance, the object appeared round.

> At first ____, the theme seemed to be in a minor key.

Comment: The ears do not swivel in the way that eyes do. Therefore the ears cannot 'glance'. Hearing just happens, without effort.

Comment: @NigelJ From [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glance): **Glance** *Noun. A brief or cursory look.* I don't see what swiveling has to do with that. Nevertheless, some animals' ears do swivel in a very similar manner to eyes.

Comment: They *point* their ears.... however, in the context desired that does not work so well.

Comment: _At first hearing_ the theme seemed to be in a minor key. But on a second hearing it was clear that it was in F major.

Comment: Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears.[Julius Caesar III 2, 1617](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-results.php?link=con&searchtype=exact&works[]=juliuscaesar&keyword1=countrymen&sortby=WorkName&pleasewait=1&msg=sr). And cock them whilst doing so [Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cock+an+ear).

Comment: @NigelJ I've heard "swiveling" used to describe the motion of cat ears before. The point is, it's not the physical motion of the sensory organ I'm interested in so much as the cursory nature of the examination. "hearing" works okay in this example, but it won't work when the examination isn't necessarily the first one. For example: "He knew at a glance that something was not right." vs "He knew at a hearing that something was not right."

Comment: -1 "Glance" as an example is not only incorrect, it's entirely misleading. "When I heard her voice for the first time, I was very impressed." Hearing is passive, vision is active.  However, the basic question is entirely valid.

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, understood. I would say 'He knew at first hearing ...' But let's wait and see if anyone has further insight into this. It will be interesting if they have. (+1).

Comment: @Kris If by passive you mean that one can't focus on a particular sound in an effort to understand it better, then I'm not sure I agree with that. As a musician I often find myself listening for a particular tone or quality which I may not consciously register without paying careful attention to the sound.  Somewhat like how it's sometimes possible to look straight at something without registering it ("hiding in plain sight"). I will agree that vision is very directional, while hearing tends to be less so (for us humans anyway).

Comment: Compare with vision in precisely the same way. You "see" things, you "look at" things, you "peer into" things .... These are active mental processes, rather than physical senses. You hear the same thing whether you are listening or not. But when you listen, you mind is more focused -- mental process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the action in `at first ____` doesn't have to imply brevity--the phrase itself does that.

Secondly, you're trying to make a generalization about a idiomatic phrase but that doesn't always work. For example, `take a listen` sounds strange as opposed to `take a look` even though they are perfectly analogous.

That said, go on CNN for a few minutes and you'll hear a reporter say it. [Some people may have a beef with it](http://wapo.st/1QmwXQI?tid=ss_mail&utm_term=.b83657253b17), but that's all part of language change; someone exercises poetic licence to generalize an idiom and if the linguistic community finds it useful/fashionable they'll adopt it.

In fact, the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA) has 3 hits for `at first listen`, so maybe in a decade or two you'll be able to use the phrase freely.

Point is, the issue you're having isn't with a word but rather trying to generalize an existing idiom. If you're not bent on using `at first ____` then it becomes trivial:

> When I first listened to (or analyzed) that theme, I thought it was in a minor key, but now that I've heard it multiple times I'm sure it's in C major.

Comment: Actually, I don't find "take a listen"/"at first listen" all that strange sounding. For some reason this just hadn't occurred to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try "at first pass"—lacks the specific auditory connotation you're looking for, but at least it *also* lacks the specific visual connotation you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

At first peek... at first peep... but that will sound trite.
at first glance... at first brush (the sound of brush gives auditory overtone)  Perhaps you could give a better adjective than "round" -- the "minor key" has so much more depth
At first glance, the object appeared round.
At first brush, the theme seemed to be in minor key.

The sight appears as, -- if you put a comma after appeared, that confirms the appearance to the speaker.
and the sound seems : perhaps change to "the theme sounds as if in minor key" plays with the auditory more.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no musician but in place of an auditory verb I would have said

> On hearing the first **[bar](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(music))**, the theme seemed to be in a minor key.

Simple Wikipedia (did I mention I am not a musician?) says

> Music that feels like **1**-2-3-4-**1**-2-3-4 will be divided into bars with four beats worth of music in each bar.

However, American speakers will probably be more familiar with the term *[measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(music))*

Comment: That only makes sense if you are hearing the music from the start. "Glance" has connotations of catching a bit at random rather than sitting and waiting for something to start, then looking away.